# MySql joining table with condition

Tags: mysql

I have these fields in my `comments` table 
`id`, `user_id`, `table`, `comment`

- The possible values of column `comments.table` is 'students' and 'teachers'.
- 'students' and 'teachers' are also tables.

What i want is if the value of `comments`.`table` == 'users' then join it to the `students` table else `teachers` table

Comment: Where is your code?  The way it works is you attempt to solve it.  If it doesn't work, we can try to help you.

Comment: The other way it works is you look for questions with practically the same title before posting your own question.

Comment: I had just solved it. Anyway thanks for all your well timed response. I love this site haha:D